# Error using DseGraphFrame with querying timestamp field

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph, dse-graph-frames

I have a `Person` label with a `created` property defined:

```
schema.propertyKey(“created”).Timestamp().single().create()
```

I get the error below when trying to use DseGraphFrame to filter for the Person label using the `created` property in `dse spark`:

> scala> g.V().hasLabel(“Person”).has(“created”,
>   P.gt("2018-10-07T14:46:26.790Z")).count().next()
>
> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(`created` >
>   1538923586790L)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in
>   '(`created` > 1538923586790L)' (timestamp and bigint).;; 'Filter
>   ((~label#270 = Person) && (created#280 > 1538923586790))…

Any idea why?

Comment: what version of the DSE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a defect in DSE version but resolved in DSE 5.1.8 and DSE 6.0.0.

see here - https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/releaseNotes/RNdse.html and look for DSP-15146